# Get all data from table who has minimum price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data in my table t1

```
unique_id   myid  price1   price2  price3  price4
1           100    20       30      40      50
2           200    12       24      48      90
3           100    15       20      30      25
4           300    100      200     300     400
5           400    10       10      20      40
6           100    5        6       7       8
7           200    1        2       3       4
```

Now i want data of particular `myid` and whose `price3` is minimum

Expected output :

```
unique_id   myid  price1   price2  price3  price4
1           100    5        6       7       8
2           200    1        2       3       4
4           300    100      200     300     400
```

I have tried following query :

```
select t1.*,t2.txn_amount from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t2.ummyid = t1.myid
where t1.myid IN (100,200,300) 
GROUP by t1.myid HAVING min(price3)
```

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: Get pairs `(myid, MIN(price3))` in subquery, use this pairs and get the whole rows from another table copy. In MySQL 8.0 - enumerate rows over `myid` ordering by `price3` in CTE, select rows where this number = 1.

Comment: Your query contains another table t2. What is it?

Comment: I am getting tax amount from t2 table.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your db version not allow over partition` you could use a join with the subquery for min values

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join  (
    select  myid, min(price3) min_price
    from table1 
    group by myid

    )  t on t.myid = t1.myid
             and t.min_price = t1.price
```

And for you case

```
    select t1.*
    , t2.txn_amount 

    from table1 t1
    inner join  (
        select  myid, min(price3) min_price
        from table1 
        group by myid

        )  t on t.myid = t1.myid
                 and t.min_price = t1.price
    left join table1 t2 on t2.ummyid = t1.myid
    where t1.myid IN (100,200,300) 
    GROUP by t1.myid
```

Comment: It returns all data.

Comment: Thank you. It works but where should i have to write my join in this query ?

Comment: you comment is not clear to  me .. try explain better ..

Comment: I have to add left join in this query. If you check my question then you will know that i am getting txn_amount  from table2. So where i have to write this left join in your given solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 then following solution should work using window function `row_number`. Here is the [demo](http://db-fiddle.com/f/9crcDUGotXbjs3Vb27SNyp/0).

```
select
  unique_id,   
  myid,  
  price1,  
  price2,  
  price3,  
  price4
from
(
  select
    unique_id,   
    myid,  
    price1,  
    price2,  
    price3,  
    price4,
    row_number() over (partition by myid order by price3) as rn
  from myTable
) subq
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use analytic functions, please use below query

```
    select unique_id,   myid,  price1,   price2,  price3,  price4 from
(slect unique_id,   myid,  price1,   price2,  price3,  price4, 
row_number() over(partition by myid order by price3) as rnk from table) qry
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solution should work:

```
Select distinct  myid,
  min(price3)
from t1 group by myid
```

Comment: You mean you didn't test it? (Note: Your query causes an error).

Comment: I've tested it and it worked on my db. What error did you get?

Comment: I got `Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.myTable.unique_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` ..also, after fixing the error, the query doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: No worries :) But now, unfortunately, it's not returning the desired columns.